# Restart a CPU that ends up unresponsive during undervolting

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel, cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm working on a set of kernel changes that allows me to undervolt my CPU at runtime. One consequence of extreme undervolting that I'm often facing is that the CPU becomes completely unresponsive.

I've tried using functions `cpu_up` and `cpu_down` in the hope of asking the kernel to restore the CPU, but to no avail.

Is there any way to recover the CPU from this state? Does the kernel have any routines that can bring back a CPU from this unresponsive state?

Comment: Beware that errors during execution could corrupt shared memory before a core totally locks up.  So even if one core can trigger another to restart, that might be a bad idea and could potentially lead to file-system corruption if the wrong bits got flipped in a mutex, or a buffer of not-yet-written FS metadata, or some memory-ordering logic that lets the right data show up in the wrong order.  If you're aware of these risks, then have fun, sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

First, to successfully benefit from undervolting, it's important that you reduce the voltage by small amounts each time (such as between 5-10 mV). Then after each step of reduction, you should check the changes to one or more hardware error metrics (typically the CPU cache error rate). Generally what happens is that error rate should increase gradually when the voltage is decreased slowly. However, at some point, an error will occur that cannot be corrected through ECC (or whatever hardware correction mechanism is being used by the processor). This is when execution becomes unreliable. Linux responds to such errors by panicking (the system will either automatically reboot or it will just hang). So you may still have chance to detect the error and choose to continue execution, but correctness is not guaranteed anymore even if you immediately increased the voltage back. So that would be a very, very dangerous thing to do. It can get very nasty very quickly. An error might occur while you're handling some another error (maybe because of the code that is handling the error, so the safest thing to do is to abort, see [Peter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545072/restart-a-cpu-that-ends-up-unresponsive-during-undervolting#comment86100602_49545072)).

Modern processors offer mechanisms to profile and handle correctable and uncorrectable hardware errors. In particular, x86 offers the Machine Check Architecture (MCA). By default, in Linux, when an uncorrectable machine check occurs, the machine check exception handler is invoked, which may abort the system (although it will try to see if it can safely recover somehow). You cannot handle that in user mode without using additional tools.

Here are the different [x86 MCE tolerance levels](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c#L72) supported by Linux:

```
struct mca_config mca_cfg __read_mostly = {
    .bootlog  = -1,
    /*
     * Tolerant levels:
     * 0: always panic on uncorrected errors, log corrected errors
     * 1: panic or SIGBUS on uncorrected errors, log corrected errors
     * 2: SIGBUS or log uncorrected errors (if possible), log corr. errors
     * 3: never panic or SIGBUS, log all errors (for testing only)
     */
    .tolerant = 1,
    .monarch_timeout = -1
};
```

Note that the default `tolerant` value is 1. But since you are modifying the kernel, you can change the way Linux handle MCEs either by changing the `tolerant` level or the handling code itself. You can get started with the [machine_check_poll](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c#L691) and [do_machine_check](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c#L1115) functions.

User-mode tools that may enable you to profile and potentially responds to machine checks include [mcelog](https://github.com/andikleen/mcelog) and [mcedaemon](https://github.com/thockin/mcedaemon). MCA is discussed in Volume 3 Chapter 15 and Chapter 16 of the Intel manual. For ARM, you can also profile cache ECC errors as discussed in [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/Chdgfjac.html).

It is very important to understand that different cores of the same chip may behave differently when reducing the voltage beyond the nominal value. This is due to process variation. So don't assume that voltage reductions would work across cores of the same chip or across chips. You're going to have to test that on every core of every chip (in case you have multiple sockets).

> I've tried using functions cpu_up and cpu_down in the hope of asking
>   the kernel to restore the CPU, but to no avail.

These functions are part of the Hotplug CPU infrastructure. Not really useful here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is CPU dependent. My answer is limited to x86_64 and s390:

Extreme undervolting is essentially unplugging the CPU, to be able to bring it back up you have to make sure that `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU` = `y` is configured.

Also, depending on the kernel version you are using you may have different teardown or setup options available to you readily.  If you are using 4.x have a look at cpuhp_* routines in `<linux/cpuhotplug.h>` in particular cpuhp_setup_state_multi`may be the one you can use to set things up ... if in doubt look at`cpuhp_setup_state_nocalls`as well as`__cpuhp_setup_state` ... Hopefully this helps :-)